# Ran php file contents in bash, could some commands be executed?

Tags: linux, bash

I accidently pasted this in bash as super user on production server.

Now I'm eating nails.

I looked through each line and most of them produce syntax error. But is there something evil that could damage server OS? or files? or anything?

This is ubuntu server 14.04.

How do I go about diagnosing what commands had been run and what did they do?

History is obvious place, but it doesn't show what has been run and by which program. Is there a way of diagnosing this kind of stupidity?

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'N%___i}IF<(o&h<;|_/0g-OYxEeU)Pq_JM@x!`S^-*[*$$#`|Lp|4R|');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '.JyD{}94,kBQB`>&>)sT@4bMl|}SxJQ~ 1NUw^RdQ;QrLVC#].#64k');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '2ClY{7eA4933w3qEQ(L>o<{`WD|t-b4B<KW;psm6qa_Mmk.f~N1$]8');
define('NONCE_KEY',        ' $QAiTez.wIq_},tNekyQYgU3:;>y-[LT-vR8X{r+kuG-t!C>');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '!#0MnA@UTy]~CN#[Akn-2M<fEuGjSH,*Bu7B[!@@.owHb:G-_PXvP_');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '%DXWY0|+SkU%!aC.aXG#T{ |YZE|X.VyfVx8QW:bX+2sZ(7cw98i');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '{d}Pn%i>?B &Q@#Dw+*Xal^eD`xK4wet8=k+F9Tr2}2H75.@+{g+)');
define('NONCE_SALT',       ']3gOf&v-43GEe`hOqnu_1TwZeqU!ZIm-8}Lm1&0;pW7d`,4[QTT');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: I very much doubt it. Everything there will produce a syntax error as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Christopher I'm not worried about PHP, because it wasn't run with PHP but bash. I'm worried some line of php could do something bad in bash :S

Comment: syntax errors and there's nothing there that will execute in a Bash shell from my cursory look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happened in a directory with (non-hidden) files in it,
then any line beginning with `*` will expand to a list of the (non-hidden) files
in the directory and so will try to execute the first one as a command<sup>1</sup>. 
If you have `.` in your `PATH`, it will try to execute *that file*;
if it is not executable, you’ll just get an error. 
If you don’t have `.` in your `PATH`, it will try to execute a command by that name. 
For example, in the unlikely event that your current directory contains the files

```
rm
romeo
sierra
tango
```

then the

```
* The base configurations of the WordPress.
```

command will expand as

```
rm romeo sierra tango The base configurations of the WordPress.
```

I expect that you would have noticed by now if that had happened
(but I advise you to do a `echo *` to see if the first file is a valid command).

There’s a similar concern for the lines beginning `/**`,
but this will probably expand to something like `/bin /dev /etc /home /lib …`,
which will result in

```
bash: /bin: is a directory
```

In the unlikely event that you have a shell variable called `table_prefix`, then

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

will expand that variable and try to execute it. 
If `table_prefix` isn’t defined, then the above will attempt to execute `=` as a command
(and there is no such command on standard Unix systems, that I know of).

Nothing else jumps out at me as a problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>   Unless there is something else in the line that makes it a syntax error,
such as an unbalanced `)`.